# Hbase client API not connecting to Hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hadoop2

I am following [this link](https://autofei.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/java-example-code-using-hbase-data-model-operations/) to insert data into my hbase. I followed all the steps and written below code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;     
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Delete;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class Startclass {

    private static Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    public static void addRecord(String tableName, String rowKey,
            String family, String qualifier, String value) throws Exception {
        try {
            HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);
            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
            put.add(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier), Bytes
                    .toBytes(value));
            table.put(put);
            System.out.println("insert recored " + rowKey + " to table "
                    + tableName + " ok.");

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
        try {
            String tablename = "hl7";

            Startclass.addRecord(tablename, "zkb", "pd", "dob", "10121993");
            Startclass.addRecord(tablename, "zkb", "pd", "id", "007");
            Startclass.addRecord(tablename, "zkb", "obr", "id", "007");
            Startclass.addRecord(tablename, "zkb", "obr", "testname", "healthec");

            Startclass.addRecord(tablename, "abc", "pd", "dob", "02051993");
            Startclass.addRecord(tablename, "abc", "pd", "id", "011");
            Startclass.addRecord(tablename, "abc", "obr", "id", "011");
            Startclass.addRecord(tablename, "abc", "obr", "testname", "matrix");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but i am getting below result

```
16/11/18 16:55:04 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-cdh5.8.0--1, built on 06/16/2016 19:37 GMT
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=quickstart.cloudera
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_67
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/home/cloudera/workspace/HbaseJav/bin:/home/cloudera/workspace/HbaseJav/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/avro.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-beanutils-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-beanutils.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-cli.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-codec.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-collections.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-compress.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-configuration.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-digester.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-httpclient.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-io.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-lang.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-logging.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-math3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/commons-net.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/guava.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-annotations.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-auth.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-hdfs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-yarn-api.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-yarn-client.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-yarn-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-yarn-server-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/htrace-core4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/jetty-util.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/jsr305.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/log4j.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/paranamer.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/protobuf-java.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/slf4j-api.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/snappy-java.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/xmlenc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/xz.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/zookeeper.jar:/home/cloudera/lib/mrunit-0.9.0-incubating-hadoop2.jar:/home/cloudera/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/home/cloudera/lib/hamcrest-all-1.1.jar:/home/cloudera/hbase-0.92.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/zookeeper.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core-2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core-mr1.jar
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=cloudera
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/cloudera
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/cloudera/workspace/HbaseJav
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 6315@quickstart.cloudera
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:41539, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
16/11/18 16:55:05 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x15876ebae4a0138, negotiated timeout = 60000
```

I have also created **hbase** table with proper column family name.
I don't know what i am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: whats the issue here, i am not seeing any error logs. Have you scanned the table "hl7" data available?

Comment: i scanned it no data is present. I can't see anything happening only this result is coming and nothing else happening.

Comment: can you manually insert data into table? how are you running this job? can you post the full log

Comment: From java i am running the application. This is the full log that i am getting. Yes manually i able to add data in hbase.

Comment: try running as hadoop job

Comment: i didn't added `core-site.xml` and `hadoop-site.xml` in my java code. Will it affect ?

Comment: no, i dont think so

Comment: same issue i am facing still not working

Comment: can you post the yarn application logs

Comment: how are you starting the class? have you put all of the needed jars into the classpath? I've just executed the code and it inserted the records w/o any problems.

Comment: @SergeyBenner yes i have inserted the jar files properly. I am clicking on the run java application from eclipse and running it.

Comment: @SergeyBenner i am following exactly what the website in the link given above says. is there anything extra i have to do ?

Comment: @animal  i just ran the code it and worked for me right away. My logs show me right after this line `[ClientCnxn.onConnected:1235] Session establishment complete on server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x15877dcae650026, negotiated timeout = 90000` - `insert recored zkb to table hl7 ok.`  You should be able to see errors at least if it fails. Like if your table is lacking column families etc.

Comment: @SergeyBenner i guess in my cloudera i am getting health issues in all cloudera services, probably that could be the reason for it.

Comment: @SergeyBenner thanks a lot for your quick response.

Comment: @animal no problem :)

Comment: @SergeyBenner can you please tell me the jar files you used. because now all my services are working fine but still i am getting same result.

Comment: @animal `java -cp .:hbase-client-0.98.9-hadoop2.jar:hbase-common-0.98.9-hadoop2.jar:hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:guava-12.0.1.jar:protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:commons-lang-2.6.jar:commons-configuration-1.6.jar:hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar:hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar:hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar:slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar:slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar:log4j-1.2.17.jar:zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:hbase-protocol-0.98.9-hadoop2.jar:htrace-core-2.04.jar:netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:commons-codec-1.7.jar Startclass`

Comment: @SergeyBenner i am having all the jar files but still same issue i am getting. I don't know what am i doing wrong. I am getting no errors nothing.

Comment: i also created hbase table using `create 'hl7','pid'` . I can't understand the reason for this behavior.

Comment: @animal  `> create 'hl7', 'pd','obr'` taken from the sample above. You should still see some errors or at least something. Are you running the sample on the same machine where the hbase is running?

Comment: I tried creating hbase your way but still getting same issue. yes i am running the sample on same machine. Although now when i checked my ram it is saying only 100 MB available of 16GB. I cant see any errors.

Comment: @SergeyBenner i am using hbase api version 0.92 is it ok ?

Comment: @animal yes it should be good enough

Comment: @SergeyBenner i removed the jar and again added it now i am getting below error
`zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server quickstart.cloudera/192.16x.x.xx:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Answer (score 1):

If you ran command 
    create 'hl7','pd','obr'
before running this code,there can be no way,it will not insert data in the table.
Only such possibility is in case of incorrect configs passed or incompatible HBase(installation)-dependency(project).

Comment: i fixed the issue by adding proper jar in my project.