# HBase FuzzyRowFilter returns no results

Tags: java, macos, scala, hbase

I'm having a hard time getting HBase's `FuzzyRowFilter` to work.

I have the following test table:

```
hbase(main):014:0> scan 'test'
ROW                                  COLUMN+CELL
 row-01                              column=colfam1:col1, timestamp=1481193793338, value=value1
 row-02                              column=colfam1:col1, timestamp=1481193799186, value=value2
 row-03                              column=colfam1:col1, timestamp=1481193803941, value=value3
 row-04                              column=colfam1:col1, timestamp=1481193808209, value=value4
 row-05                              column=colfam1:col1, timestamp=1481193812737, value=value5
5 row(s) in 0.0200 seconds
```

Here is my Java code (I started with Scala, but the results are the same - none):

```
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost:2182");
    conf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000");
    conf.set("hbase.rootdir", "/hbase");


    try {
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.setCaching(5);

        byte[] rowKeys = Bytes.toBytesBinary("???-01");
        byte[] fuzzyInfo = {0x01,0x01,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00};
        FuzzyRowFilter fuzzyFilter = new FuzzyRowFilter(
                Arrays.asList(
                        new Pair<byte[], byte[]>(
                                rowKeys,
                                fuzzyInfo)));

        System.out.println("### fuzzyFilter: " + fuzzyFilter.toString());

        scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytesBinary("colfam1"));
        scan.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytesBinary("row-01"));
        scan.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytesBinary("row-05"));
        scan.setFilter(fuzzyFilter);

        Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
        Table table = conn.getTable(TableName.valueOf("test"));
        ResultScanner results = table.getScanner(scan);

        int count = 0;
        int limit = 100;
        for ( Result r : results ) {
            System.out.println("" + r.toString());
            if (count++ >= limit) break;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I simply do not get any results back from the server. If I comment out the line `scan.setFilter(fuzzyFilter);`, I get the exepcted results:

```
keyvalues={row-01/colfam1:col1/1481193793338/Put/vlen=6/seqid=0}
keyvalues={row-02/colfam1:col1/1481193799186/Put/vlen=6/seqid=0}
keyvalues={row-03/colfam1:col1/1481193803941/Put/vlen=6/seqid=0}
keyvalues={row-04/colfam1:col1/1481193808209/Put/vlen=6/seqid=0}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a bug in HBase (version 1.2.2)? I am using the version installed through Homebrew on latest Mac OS Sierra.

## Update

On a Cloudera Hadoop cluster running CDH 5.7 with HBase 1.2.0-cdh5.7.0, I get the desired output for rowkey `row-01`. The error must somehow be related to my local setup.

## Solution

Indeed, the problem was that HBase server installation and client JAR versions did not match. In my case, I was using the artifacts

- hbase-common
- hbase-client
- hbase-server

with version `1.2.0-cdh5.7.0` instead of `1.2.2`.

My mistake was assuming that minor version differences would not have a large impact, but apparently Cloudera has applied some major changes in their versions with respect to the official code base. Changing to the official version `1.2.2` made the `FuzzyRowFilter` work as expected.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why (s)he downvoted my question? I believe it clearly states the problem and my previous attempts to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should print only rowkey of row-01 as can be perceived from the filter condition.
There is no such bug and it will work as expected as I have been using same for some time now.
Check your configurations,dependencies,etc.
Due to versioning,many times libraries and their clients becom incompatible.
Lets take a simple example:

```
class ServerVersionA {
public static void getData() {
    return DataOject(data with headerVersionA);
}
```

}

```
class ClientVersionB {
public void showData() {
    DataObject dataObject = makeRequest(params);
    //Check whether data recieved is of version B after veryfying header                                         boolean status=validate(dataObject);
    if (status) {
        doIO(dataObject);
    }
}
```

}

In this case,if the header does not match,client does simply sit idle.
These kind of issues are mostly taken care of but sometimes they creep in.
If we look at the sources of installation and client version,we can find out why data is not being returned and no exception is propagated.

Comment: Great to hear you got the filter to work. But don't you agree that the behavior of the HBase server is weird? If there is a mismatch of dependencies or configs, shouldn't the server report an error instead of returning an empty result? Anyway, I would be glad about *specific* hints towards solving my problem.

Comment: It does so in most cases but in cases like version mismatch(jar and installation) it does kind of no-op without throwing even warnings.

Comment: For example you can refer to [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676953/hbase-client-api-not-connecting-to-hbase/41040415?noredirect=1#comment69289550_41040415) and look at the problem and solution.

Comment: If still you are getting errors you can send me information on hbase download link and your pom or classpath variables.

Comment: You are right, the problem was using hbase jars from Cloudera repo. Using the official jars with matching version solved my problem. Could you include your comments about NoOps in case of jar version mismatches in your answer? Then I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: It is not exactly no-op(kind of!).

Comment: For example,lets take a simple example:    class ServerVersionA {
    public static void getData(){
        return DataOject(headerVersionA,data);
    }
}

class ClientVersionB{
    public void showData(){
        DataObject dataObject=makeRequest(params);
        //Check whether data recieved is of version B
        boolean status=validate(dataObject);
        if (status){
            doIO(dataObject);
        }
    }
}

Comment: If you look in the sources of installed hbase-version and client jar version,you can find similar root issues.These kind of issues are a major culprit for version related problems.This is a very simple example of what might happen.If you want to identify the real thing,you can add versions of you installation and client library,so that I can look at sources.Thanks.

Comment: I accepted your answer as the solution. However, I would be glad if you could include the main points of your comments into your answer, so that future visitors of this question find the solution at a glance.